# Spring Data @JoinColumn and Entity Update

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

First of all, I lacked the appropriate title to give to this question. Feel free to update it.

**Problem Statement**

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Session {
    @Column(name = "last_screen_id")
    private Long lastScreenId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "last_screen_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne
    private Screen lastScreen;

    // Getters and setters for lastScreenId
    // Getter for lastScreen (I don't have a setter for lastScreen object since lastScreen object is marked as insertable=false and updatable=false)
}
```

If I update the `lastScreenId` I want the `lastScreen` object to be updated. For example I set the `lastScreenId` from `1` to `2` using `session.setLastScreenId(2)` I want the `lastScreen` object to be the object with id `2`

So here is what I have tried:

1. Just update the `lastScreenId`. I expected the `lastScreen` object to be updated since the `session` object is still a **MANAGED** entity

   Fails since the `lastScreen` object remains to be the previous object
2. Update the `lastScreenId` and save the `session` object using a `SessionRepository` and replace the current `session` object to the new `session` object saved in the database

   `session= sessionRepository.save(screen);`

   Fails since the `lastScreen` object is not pulled from the database
3. Use another method to save the `session` with a different transaction

   ```
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Session saveSessionInANewTransaction(Session session) {

        return sessionRepository.save(session);

    }
   ```

   This one fails too.

Comment: That is not how you would update a reference. Remove the `lastScreenId` field and set the `@JoinColumn` to `insertable = true, updatable = true`. Then you set the whole `Screen` object to the `Session` before saving that change to the database

Comment: @XtremeBaumer this is more an answer than a comment. If you can come to a full answer, please add it as one :)

Answer (score 0):

Any reason that you need to duplicate mapping the "last_screen_id" column in the same object ?

If not , I suggest you to change it to only map it to a `Screen` entity which is much more simple:

```
@Entity
public class Session {

    @JoinColumn(name = "last_screen_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToOne
    private Screen lastScreen;

}
```

To update the Screen from ID 1 to ID 2 , you have to first get new Screen and set it to the `Session` 's `lastScreen.` Throw exception if there is no ID for the new `Screen` :

```
public void updateSessionLastScreen(Long sessionId, Long newScreenId){
    Session session  = sessionRepository.findbyId(sessionId).orElseThrow(()-> new RuntimeException("Session does not exist"));  
    Screen newScreen = screenRepository.findById(newScreenId).orElseThrow(()-> new RuntimeException("Screen does not exist")); 
    session.setLastScreen(newScreen);
}
```